# Android Location network provider is always false

Tags: java, android

```
LocationManager locationManager= (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gpsIsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean networkIsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    System.out.println("gpsIsEnabled  " +gpsIsEnabled +" \n networkIsEnabled  "+networkIsEnabled);

    if(networkIsEnabled)
    {
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
    else if(gpsIsEnabled)
    {
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);  
    }

    System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
    onLocationChanged(location);
    System.out.print(location.getLatitude());


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I am always getting false for network enabled when I have it enabled in my phone and I have also tried with wifi and it always false.  I have tested with a galaxy S5 and always false.

Comment: Are you testing on an emulator or a real device? http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#geo

Comment: We need the code in where you're calling locationmanager. So, please, post it, and a piece of the error in the logcat will be useful too.

Comment: on both it gets null and I have the gps enabled and  allow location

Answer (score -1):

Location settings must be turned on in order for it to work.

Comment: In the comments they state location is enabled.